# apachemq exception during JMS processing

Tags: java, spring, apache, jms

can somebody explain in simple words please how to add my domain object to apachemq trusted objects. already carefully read apache tutorial where it is said that script needs to be added to /bin/env but i don't have an env file in my bin folder. thanks

> 2016-04-08 16:55:49 ERROR AdviceController:23 - CONTROLLER ASPECT:
>   EXCEPTION IN METHOD -> class
>   org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException 2016-04-08 16:55:49
>   ERROR AdviceController:31 - Uncategorized exception occured during JMS
>   processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to
>   build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker.
>   Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class
>   domain.Client! This class is not trusted to be serialized as
>   ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at
>   http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on
>   how to configure trusted classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES","domain");
```